# I have this issue when I am using http package in flutter {The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'}

Tags: api, flutter, http

**I have this issue when I was using the get method.
And here it is my loading screen contains the error with the first parameter of the http.get method
**

```
import 'dart:convert';

class NetworkHelper {
final String url;
NetworkHelper(this.url);

Future getData() async {
 final response = await http.get(url);
 if (response.statusCode == 200) {
   String data = response.body;
   return jsonDecode(data);
 } else {
   print(response.statusCode);
 }
}
} `
```

Comment: please add more description of your error, would be great if you give it with description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `Uri.parse()` to convert string to URL.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a Uri :

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

```
Future getData() async {
 final response = await http.get(Uri.https(url));
 if (response.statusCode == 200) {
   String data = response.body;
   return jsonDecode(data);
 } else {
   print(response.statusCode);
 }
}
}
```